# Steady-state solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

This is the problem given:

[image]

I am not entirely sure what my Professor expected from an answer, but it seems I am to find the coefficient, angular frequency, and phase of the non-homogenous solution only.
I know that the steady state means $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, but how can I know the initial condition for $y$?

Using method of undetermined coefficients I got $$y=c_1\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{19}}{3}\right)t+c_2\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{19}}{3}\right)-\frac{68}{353}\sin(2t)+\frac{32}{353}\cos(2t)$$

for the solution.

Is the answer simply $$A= \frac{32}{353},\, B=2,\, C=0?$$

Also is this what the solution should look like?

[image: The blue line is the solution y and the green dashed line is the signal $4\cos(2t)$]

The blue line is the solution y and the green dashed line is the signal $4cos(2t)$

Comment: Your solution is the one having $c_1=0$ and for $t$ long enough to damp out the other exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably expected to use the fact that
$$
a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x-\varphi),
$$
where $\varphi$ satisfies
$$
\cos \varphi=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\\
\sin \varphi=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.
$$